# Windows 10 Explorer doesn't start

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

This problem has persisted for several months but it comes up periodically. My temporary fix is to restart but I've gotten annoyed.

When I click on a folder, it starts but when I start up explorer.exe itself, it wont work. Also when I right click on a folder or file, it crashes explorer and restarts it.

I've tried restarting the process and chosen the Launch Folder In Different Process and always use Icons, Never Thumbnails.

I have tried disabling shell extensions with third party software but no luck.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal configuration does this behavior exhibit itself?

Comment: After restarts, the problem won't show but a while after I restart, it continues the problem. @Ramhound